# CopyLocal always persists to true in VS2012

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, reference, msbuild

I have a weird issue with one VS2012 project. We're trying to redirect the 3rd-party project references to a different folder than the main.exe folder (eg \bin) (like this [Can Visual Studio compile project references into a different folder then the main .exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/596416/can-visual-studio-compile-project-references-into-a-different-folder-then-the-ma))

Whenever I set the CopyLocal property to False, when I rebuild the solution the property returns to True.

When editing the csproj, under each `<Reference Include="...">` I can set the `<Private>` tag to False, but again when the build starts, the property returns to True.

I've searched high and low but can't find a reason why this property persists. Anything I'm missing?

Many thanks,

Comment: This makes little sense.  Did you forget to check-out the project file from source control?

Comment: Everything was checked out, the csproj and the files within.